# get DataGridView selected row value to other form

Tags: c#, winforms

i want to get the value of the `selected row` in the DataGridView named `dgSales`
and make a method in other forms using the `dgSales` values.

```
VoidItem vi = new VoidItem
{
    VoidID = 1000,
    TransactionNo = fpos.dgSales.Rows[]//here i want to get the value of the selected row and cell 3.
};
```

Comment: @JohnG noted sir, sorry, i edited it already

Comment: The `DataGridView` has a `SelectedRows` collection. The last selected row would be at … `gridName.SelectedRows[0]` …and the third cells value would be… `gridName.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a global class file to your project and declare your fields as
public ie

public string BookingId = "";

In the Selection Change event of the grid do

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gvBookings.SelectedRows)
{
    GlobalClass.BookingId = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
}
```

Then you can use the global variables anywhere else in your code.